# Getting "premature end of file /syslinux/vmlinuz0" during Fedora 22 installation

Tags: linux, bootable-media, liveusb, fedora-22

I am trying to install Fedora 22 64 bit using an USB. I have created the bootable USB stick using Fedora live USB creator. When I start the boot, I get this error.

```
 error: premature end of file /syslinux/vmlinuz0

 error: you need to load the kernel first
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the flash drive on which I created the live image and it worked fine.

So far of all the flash drives that I've tried to use, only 'Lexar' flash drive worked.